# How to reference a particular Panel used in the ui?

Tags: python, panel

I want to change the category value of a panel. And I can get all bpy_class of a module like this:

```
import bpy_types
typemap_list = bpy_types.TypeMap.get(__name__, ())

for cls_weakref in typemap_list:
    cls = cls_weakref()
    if cls.bl_label == 'My Panel'
        cls.bl_category = 'New category name' # changed here
        break
```

But is it possible to get the right class without needing the loop?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the panel in a single operation but not by label, since panels labels aren't necessarily unique, you should use the panel name.

eg:

```
cls = getattr(bpy.types, "VIEW3D_PT_view3d_display")
```

---

Note that `bpy_types.TypeMap` is part of Blenders internal logic which you're not meant to touch! :)